# Ical.net viewing event data from calendar in .net and c#

Tags: c#

I've set up a console app to test out Ical.net. I have this code that is pulling the occurrences of these events from the calendar (which is working great); but I want to be able to view the other details that exist within these event objects; and I don't see in the documentation how to view the details.

Here is my code:

```
var calendar = new Calendar();
var recurrenceRule = new RecurrencePattern("FREQ=DAILY");

var vEvent = new CalendarEvent
{
    Start = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Parse("2018-10-01T07:00")),
    End = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Parse("2018-10-01T08:00")),
    Description = "Test Description on event object",
    Name = "Event Title 1",
    RecurrenceRules = new List<RecurrencePattern> { recurrenceRule }
};
calendar.Events.Add(vEvent);

recurrenceRule = new RecurrencePattern("FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=4;WKST=SU");
vEvent = new CalendarEvent
{
    Start = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Parse("2018-10-01T07:00")),
    End = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Parse("2018-10-01T08:00")),
    Description = "Test2 event description yo!",
    Name = "Event Title 2",
    RecurrenceRules = new List<RecurrencePattern> { recurrenceRule }
};
calendar.Events.Add(vEvent);

var searchStart = DateTime.Parse("2018-10-01");
var searchEnd = DateTime.Parse("2018-10-31");
var occurrences = calendar.GetOccurrences(searchStart, searchEnd);

foreach (var item in occurrences)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Updated**

I was able to view some of the event details by adding the following before my `Console.ReadLine();`

*Code Addition:*

```
foreach (var item in calendar.Children)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

My only issue now is how would I tie up the occurrence date, this item.name, and the event description together into one object / things that reference each other?

***Complete Code:***

```
    var calendar = new Calendar();
var recurrenceRule = new RecurrencePattern("FREQ=DAILY");

var vEvent = new CalendarEvent
{
    Start = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Parse("2018-10-01T07:00")),
    End = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Parse("2018-10-01T08:00")),
    Description = "Test Description on event object",
    Name = "Event Title 1",
    RecurrenceRules = new List<RecurrencePattern> { recurrenceRule }
};
calendar.Events.Add(vEvent);

recurrenceRule = new RecurrencePattern("FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=4;WKST=SU");
vEvent = new CalendarEvent
{
    Start = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Parse("2018-10-01T07:00")),
    End = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Parse("2018-10-01T08:00")),
    Description = "Test2 event description yo!",
    Name = "Event Title 2",
    RecurrenceRules = new List<RecurrencePattern> { recurrenceRule }
};
calendar.Events.Add(vEvent);

var searchStart = DateTime.Parse("2018-10-01");
var searchEnd = DateTime.Parse("2018-10-31");
var occurrences = calendar.GetOccurrences(searchStart, searchEnd);

foreach (var item in occurrences)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}

foreach (var item in calendar.Children)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    //result: Event Title 1, Event Title 2
    //Does not have access to even description, start, or end values. 
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Children` returns a list of `ICalendarObject`.

If you want to retrieve the event details, you have to cast back to `CalendarEvent`:

```
foreach (ICalendarObject item in calendar.Children)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);

    if (item is CalendarEvent calendarEvent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(calendarEvent.Description);
        Console.WriteLine(calendarEvent.Start);
        Console.WriteLine(calendarEvent.End);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Event Title 2
>   Test2 event description yo!
>   01/10/2018 07:00:00
>   01/10/2018 08:00:00

To get the source event from the occurrences, you can do this:

```
foreach (var item in occurrences)
{
    var sourceEvent = item.Source as CalendarEvent;
    Console.WriteLine(sourceEvent.Description);
    Console.WriteLine(sourceEvent.Start);
    Console.WriteLine(sourceEvent.End);
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for breaking that down for me.

Do you happen to know how to link up the occurrence list with their related events?

Comment: I cannot believe it was that simple!